# How to sync a local repo so that any local submodules which aren't in remote are wiped?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-update-ref

Let's say you have a local repo and want it to be exactly as the last commit in your remote repo.

These are the steps that I'm typing in order to achieve this:

```
cd <main repo>
git clean -fxd       (clean all untracked files that aren't submodules)
git submodule foreach git clean -fxd     (clean all untracked files in submodules)
git reset --hard             (clean all uncommited changes in our main repo)
git submodule foreach git reset --hard    (clean all uncommited changes in submodules)

git submodule update --init --recursive         (update all submodules with one on remote repo)
```

The problem is that these **won't delete any extra submodules that are in my local repo** but not in the remote repo.

Any help in improving my series of steps would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `git clone`  ???

Comment: @RonnieRoyston That kind of misses the point, doesn't it? If you have made some local changes and want to ensure that they can be runereproducibly from an otherwise clean repo, starting over from a clean slate is cumbersome and potentially expensive in terms of time and disk space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean#Documentation/git-clean.txt---force):

> If the Git configuration variable `clean.requireForce` is not set to
> false, git clean will refuse to delete files or directories unless
> given `-f` or `-i`. **Git will refuse to modify untracked nested git
> repositories (directories with a .git subdirectory) unless a second `-f`
> is given.**

so `git clean -dffx`